# Django 2.0 url parameters in get_queryset

Tags: python, django, url, django-views

I would like to filter subcategories based on the category id from the URL

For a constant value, it works without a problem

```
return Subcategory.objects.filter(category = 1)
```

views.py

```
class SubcategoriesListView(ListView):
    model = Subcategory
    template_name = 'app/categories/index.html'
    def get_queryset(self):
        return Subcategory.objects.filter(category = category_id)
```

urls.py

```
path('categories/<int:category_id>/', app.views.SubcategoriesListView.as_view(), name='subcategories'),
```

models.py

```
class Subcategory(models.Model):
   title = models.CharField(max_length=30)
   category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Traceback

```
NameError at /categories/1/
name 'category_id' is not defined

views.py in get_queryset
return Subcategory.objects.filter(category = category_id)
```

Comment: It is `self.kwargs['category_id']`.

Comment: @Wariored you are wrong, `category_id` still not defined.

Comment: `self.kwargs['category_id']`and then `return Subcategory.objects.filter(category__id = category_id)`

Comment: @AugustinLaville updated

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can obtain the URI positional and named parameters in a class-based view with `self.args` (a tuple) and `self.kwargs` (a dictionary) respectively.

Here you defined the `category_id` as a named parameter, so you can obtain its corresponding value with `self.kwargs['category_id']`:

```
class SubcategoriesListView(ListView):
    model = Subcategory
    template_name = 'app/categories/index.html'
    def get_queryset(self):
        return Subcategory.objects.filter(category_id=self.kwargs['category_id'])
```

Since the `id` is an integer, you thus filter on `category_id`, not on `category`.

Comment: This was the exact answer I was looking for, thank you.  [And thanks to SO for popping this as the recommended question to check once I pasted in my code snippets into asking this question for myself]