# How to retrieve all items created by a user using the django rest framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I  am trying to get only courses belonging to a particular user below I have the model, serializer and view I am using to try and achieve this. If I delete the entire get_queryset function from the view the api returns the appropriate user and every course created by every user. If get_queryset remains, the api always returns user not found and still gives every course that exists. Can anyone point me to how I can achieve my desired result.

view:

```
class UserDetail(generics.RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):
    permission_classes = [IsProfileOwnerOrReadOnly]
    # queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        user = self.request.user
        queryset = User.objects.all()
        if user is not None:
            queryset = queryset.filter(courses__owner_id=user.id)
        return queryset
```

serializer

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    courses = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(
        many=True, queryset=Course.objects.all())
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['id', 'username', 'courses']
```

Model

```
class Course (models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    description = models.TextField()
    pub_date = models.DateField(default=date.today)
    owner = models.ForeignKey('auth.User', related_name='courses', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

Comment: How did you define the URL mapped to your view? If you want to have the courses created by a particular user, your URL must allow to choose a user id. Something like `https://api.yourcourses.com/user/<user_id>/courses` that you can achieve with https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/routers/#drf-nested-routers

Comment: If you want to use the `user` given by the authentication middleware, in this case, you should be able to directly use `self.request.user.courses` or `Courses.objects.filter(owner=self.request.user)`

Comment: @AlexandreS the url is given as     path('users/<int:pk>/', views.UserDetail.as_view()),

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to filter objects by user

```
    class CreatePostsView(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
        model = Post
        serializer_class = PostsSerializer


        def get_queryset(self):
            user = self.request.user

            return Post.objects.filter(owner=user)
```

Answer (score 1):

```py
class CoursesByOwnerView(RetrieveModelMixin, GenericViewSet):
        serializer_class = YourModelSerializer
        authentication_classes =[TokenAuthentication,]
        permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated,]
    

        def list(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
           course_taker = self.request.user
           courses = YourModel.objects.filter(owner=course_taker).values('your_model_fields')
           return Response(courses)
```

Answer (score -1):

Given your answer in the comments:

- Either you use `self.request.user` given by the authentication middleware. In this case, it will only work for authenticated users, and you can't see courses for another User.
- Either you use the endpoint `users/<int:pk>/` you mentioned. In this case, you can fetch the user with:

```py
class UserDetail(generics.RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):
    permission_classes = [IsProfileOwnerOrReadOnly]
    serializer_class = UserSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        return UserDetail.objects.filter(pk=self.kwargs["pk"])
```

See this thread if you need another example: [Django 2.0 url parameters in get_queryset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51755692/django-2-0-url-parameters-in-get-queryset)

EDIT: In both cases, change your UserSerializer with:

```py
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    courses = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(
        many=True, read_only=True)
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['id', 'username', 'courses']
```

Comment: this doesn't work, it get the details for just one user but when I'm using the browsable api, i  still see every course for the put request. I think the issues is from the courses variable in the serializer but i dont know how to get just the user courses instead of all courses.

Comment: Indeed, your serializer has the argument `queryset=Course.objects.all()`. Try to remove this argument and set `read_only=True`.